# Notifications in android by comparing the system time with database values using background service

Tags: android

I am developing an android app.I wan to provide five notifications per day.I will store the notification time in sqlite database.Then I compare this db notification time with the devices time in a repeating loop using service.But the notification will not work properly.Forceclose appeared.....I need the help

Comment: I have five notifications.Not only one.I think AlarmManager is useful in the case of only one notification trigerring at a specific time.I have to compare my five notifications with databse notification times.Is service is needed in this case.please help...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) for scheduling tasks. Register a `BroadcastReceiver` and create the `Notification` in its `onReceive()` method. Then initialize the `AlarmManager` with a `PendingIntent` to your `BroadcastReceiver` using the `set()` method. Hope this helps.

Comment: I want to compare my five notification times with databae time values.Inthis case Alarmmanager is useful? Or service is better..?

Comment: @user1544383, What for do you need these comparisons? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to produce muslim prayer time notifications.User will set the five notifications and save into the database.Then I compare these times with the devices time in a service...

Comment: @user1544383, So why can't you just set 5 alarms at different times?

Comment: I think If I set five alarms at different times,the last setted alarm is triggered.Is it true?

Comment: @user1544383, If you set them properly they all are triggered.

Comment: You mean I can set these five alarms using one alarm clock?

Comment: @user1544383, What's alarm clock?

Comment: Egor: Instead of setting five different alarms, How can I can set these nitifications  through AlarmManager using the db stored values?

Comment: @user1544383, You can't skip setting five different alarms, you just need to call set() on AlarmManager with five different time values and that's all.

Comment: @user1544383, What kind of sample code? You should search for it yourself, there are tons of tutorials on this topic, just put a little effort in it.

Comment: Egor: How can I set Alarm if my db stored values in the format of(tim1-4:50 AM)..time1 is variable that contains the value 4:50 AM..